# What do I need to learn for accessing data from mssql database?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am learning asp.net core mvc and API. I can simply work on it for CRUD operation. But, I get confused for accessing data from multiple tables like listing all categories with showing number of items each categories contains. What I need to learn for example Lina, entity framework code first, ado.net? I am currently using entity framework code first.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) a simple object mapper for **.NET**.
What I Understood from your problem is that you have multiple tables and you want to query them and map the query result in your c# or vb code.Here I will show simple mapping of query result to c# objects.
Suppose you have three tables category_1,category_2 and category_3.
Lets say each table have two columns named itemName and ItemValue.
Lets create c# class corresponding to each table.

```
class category_1{
    string ItemName {get;set};
    int ItemValue {get;set;};
    }
 class category_2{
        string ItemName {get;set};
        int ItemValue {get;set;};
    }
 class category_3{
        string ItemName {get;set};
        int ItemValue {get;set;};
    }
```

Suppose your querying three tables and map the result of query to respective object in c#.
let our sql query be as follows:

```
string sql = @"select * from category_1;select * from category_2;select * from category_3;"
```

Here we have three select statements and each select statement will give you result of respective table.Lets query the above sql to database using dapper and map them to c# object as follows.

```
List<category_1> lstCotegory1 = new List<category_1>();
List<category_2> lstCotegory2 = new List<category_2>();
List<category_3> lstCotegory3 = new List<category_3>();

using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql))
{
   lstCotegory1  =  multi.Read<category_1>().ToList(); // map first select statement
   lstCotegory2   = multi.Read<category_2>().ToList();  // map second select statement
   lstCotegory3   = multi.Read<category_3>().ToList();   // map third select statement.
}
```

This is how you can return results of multiple queries and map them to appropriate object. I know you can do better than this but to understand we have to go with simple example.Hope this will help.